# Do I have to have an exhaust fan above my stove?

Tags: bathroom, kitchens, exhaust-fan

My stove is smack dab next to the back door (which is easy to open and close).  Do I have to have a functioning exhaust fan?  Or can I just close it off to solve a draft problem I am having?

And same question for the bathroom.

These fans were but in by a DIY enthusiast before we bought the house.  They do a lousy job of venting when they're turned on, and they're giving me horrible drafts.

Comment: I know that exhaust fans in bathrooms and certain other rooms with no windows are required, but not sure about the vent hood.  Is it a gas stove?  That might make a difference.  Also, what is the location?

Comment: Electric stove.  Upstate NY.

Comment: You don't _have_ to have one, usually, but you should want one; it keeps your whole house cleaner by sucking out greasy fumes before they settle on cabinets, counters, baseboards, even ceilings. This not only makes your place cleaner, it reduces the grease surface area which when large, attracts insects and rodents. Inside-only fans use an ineffective grease filter that doesn't help nearly as much as pumping it all outside would. Cover the openings with lids made from styrofoam insulation to avoid drafts, but don't shoot yourself in the foot by removing a very good thing.

Comment: @dandavis - Opening the back door would not give as good a result, I take it. // Can you tell me more about your styrofoam idea?

Comment: you just trace out a template of the vent opening with AL foil, then transfer to a sheet of pink house insulation or whatever. You can embed magnets into the foam if your duct grill is steel, or velcro if not. You just pop it on when you're not cooking, take it off when you are or all fall/spring as needed. Wall/Contact paper can dress it up for cheap. You can use weather stripping along the peremiter to get a good tight seal if needed. You can also buy [pre-made ones](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/lr003458-lr045003-insulation-engine-hood-for_60863163269.html), but that's not DIY.

Comment: @dandavis - The inspiration and the installation would be in keeping with the DIY mindset. // I don't understand how to use it.  There is a metal grill right now.  Are you saying I would put this thingie over top of the grill?  To get a tight fit, I'd have to cut away maybe 1/4 inch, over a square (the shape of the grill).  Do you use one?  A picture would be very helpful.

Comment: well i did, then i moved... Yes, it "snaps" onto the grill, and should be about the same dimesions or slightly larger. You can decorate with paper/cloth/contact/paint, or press-on tiles to match a backsplash. you can cut a lip with a box cutter or xacto. I smooshed mine onto the meta grill/filter to trace it, then drilled small shallow holes on the 4 corners of the foam and hot-glued super magnets into those holes to hold in place.

Comment: @dandavis and it's not a fire hazard?

Comment: I'd check how the fan ducting was run, make sure it's stretched out all the way and hasn't collapsed/...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I haven't turned it on since I moved in in August.  How is that going to make my kitchen warmer?

Comment: @aparente001 -- a collapsed or unstretched flex duct would explain why the fans do a lousy job of venting at least...

Comment: @dandavis - I'm now ready to cover my vent as you suggested, but I'm concerned about fire safety.  I have a careless teenager.  I haven't been able to figure out if there's a type of foam insulation board that is fireproof.  Do you want me to write a Question?

Comment: some experiments: run the stove on high for 5 mins with no pot and with the fan off and feel the grill. it shouldn't be hot enough to catch anything on fire. also try burning the material you choose; it shouldn't go up like a torch. Most these days have legal fuel load considerations, some might be relatively fire-proof. Boric acid (roach powder) can treat textiles to make them flame proof. You can make a rigid foam light enough to float with concrete+soap and forced air. Rockwool, charcloth, vermiculite, perlite, and steel wool can insulate w/o fuel load.

Comment: @dandavis - My concern is my teenager.  He has Tourette Syndrome and has been known to start a harebrained kitchen project at 2 am under the effects of insomnia.  He knows he's not supposed to fry things in oil when a parent isn't handy, but he's extremely impulsive.  Imagine a three-year-old that's six foot two, eyes of brown.  May I skip the five-minute heating experiment?

Comment: You'll know best what to do. I'm just trying to offer some ideas. A lot of hoods have plastic bulb covers, so absolute fire proofness may not be required: fans are often left off after all...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Code requires an exhaust vent capable of a minimum for 150 cfm. (See M1507.3 and Table M1507.3)

The duct shall be metal and extend to the exterior.

If the exhaust fan exceed 400 cfm, then makeup air is required. (See IMC Chapter 5)